# Ubuntu 22.04 videos look like stop motion animation when I try to watch them

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, freeze, 22.04

I try to watch movies in my SSD or videos in internet and they look like stop motion animation. They also look freezy.

I tried three different things:

1. Installing Radeon Vega graphics drivers. It didn't work
2. I also tried updating the open graphics drivers (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`) It didn't work.
3. Finally I tried a dist-upgrade and it didn't work.

I removed those previously installed drivers

This is my neofetch output.

[image: 1]

Results of `inxi -G` :

[image]

Comment: Strange. Running 22.04 on a Thinkpad with amd does not give any problems. Did you remove those previously installed drivers?
What does `inxi -G`say?  Copy the output into your answer (**NOT** in a comment) by using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1418943/edit) link

Comment: I have almost exactly same laptop with the same CPU and GPU, but with '14 screen (X412DA). I have no problems. But i see that the system is borked.. `amdgpu` should be in use, but it seems to be blacklisted, or the system is loaded with `nomodeset` option. Also oibaf ppa doesn't help either. If you reinstall the system all should work well.